Show that every group of order $2 · 3 · 5 · 67$ has a normal subgroup of order $5$.

Show that if $G$ is a group of order $2010 = 2 · 3 · 5 · 67$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $5$.

I tried use Sylow's theorem to show that $k_5=1$.
$k_5$ is equal to $1$, $6$, or $201$.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

What techniques do you know to rule out the possibilities that $k_5=6$ or $k_5=201$?

I realy don't know how to do that.
